# one nic with 2 gateways

Tags: networking

Is it possible two give an interface 2 different gateways?

This is my config, and I want to add a second gateway (192.168.1.71).

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto em1
iface em1 inet static
address 192.168.1.103
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.250
```

Answer (score 1):

No.

The "gateway" of which you speak is actually the "default gateway", the place where the system sends TCP/IP packets for which it has no other routing instructions (see `man ip-route`). How can there be TWO "last resorts"? There cannot be.

This sounds like an "XY problem" - what would you want to achieve with a second "gateway"?